# Securing Firebase data

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm attempting to setup Firebase rules for the first time. What I want to do is restrict access to logged in users so that they can only access their data.  Their own data is at `users` and `usercontacts`. Anyone can write to the `contactmessages` route and nobody can read.

Is this set of rules doing what I expect it to do?  I tried it in the simulator and got a `simulated write denied` error.  I could be doing something wrong on the simulator.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants read/write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "usercontacts":{
        "$user_id": {
              ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
              ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
        }
    },
    "contactmessages": {
        ".read" : false,
        ".write" : "$user_id === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the write operation that you're trying that fails? So the full path that you write to, the active uid (if any), the data that you're writing and the existing data (that is relevant to the write+rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with your last write rule:

```
"contactmessages": {
    ".read" : false,
    ".write" : "$user_id === auth.uid"
}
```

You are using $user_id but there isn't any $user_id to reference to. Instead you should use this rule if you want anyone to be able to write here:

```
".write" : true
```

Or this rule if you want every authenticated user to be able to write:

```
".write" : "auth != null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        "$userId":{
             ".read": "(auth != null) && ($userId === auth.uid)",
             ".write": "(auth != null) && ($userId === auth.uid)"
        }
     },
     "usercontacts": {
        "$userId": {
              ".read": "(auth != null) && ($userId === auth.uid)",
              ".write": "(auth != null) && ($userId === auth.uid)"
        }
      },
      "contactmessages": {
        "$userId": {
              ".read": "(auth != null) && ($userId === auth.uid)",
              ".write": "(auth != null) && ($userId === auth.uid)"
        }
      }
  }
}
```